# Trying to rewrite text files in 'Latin-1' results in wrong characters for letters with accents

Tags: python, encoding, txt

I am trying to open and change several text files. My files are in 'Latin-1' but when I use `f.read` all the letters with accents are converted into "ã".
My code is:

```
for dname, dirs, files in os.walk("mydirection"):
    for fname in files:
        fpath = os.path.join(dname, fname)
        with open(fpath, encoding='latin-1') as f:
            text = f.read()
            text = text.replace(r'- ', '')
            # remove punctuation
            text = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', ' ', text)
        with open(fpath, 'w', encoding='latin-1') as file:
            file.write(text)
```

Is it possible to write and change the text files and keep them in 'Latin-1'?

Example of text file: "élève,"

What I want: "élève" (or if it is not possible "eleve")

What I am obtaining: "ã l ã ve"

Comment: You're using `encoding='latin-1'` when you read the files.  Why aren't you also doing that when you write them?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the encoding on write?

Comment: If I specify the encoding when I write, it also does not work

Comment: Have you restored the original version of the files? Currently your code overwrites the existing files, so the next time you run your code it will read the file as you modified it, not as it was before you started coding.

Comment: Yes, I restored the original files. Every time that I try, I delete the wrong final output, and copy the original files to the folder again.

Comment: The problem is in the ```f.read```. It is in this part that is converting the "é" into "ã "

Comment: The most plausible thing I can come up with is that the input file is in fact encoded as UTF-8 not Latin-1. In UTF-8, most accented characters (including `é`) are encoded as `0xc3` followed by another byte. If those bytes were decoded as Latin-1, then `0xc3` would decode to `Ã`. But that doesn't explain why you'd see lower-case `ã`.

Comment: Thank you, slothrop for your comment. Is it not possible to solve in that case?

Comment: @MGFern if that *is* the case, then just specify `encoding='utf-8'` when reading (or omit it, since it's the default), and you can still specify `encoding='latin-1'` when writing if you want your output in that format. However, I'm not sure this *is* the problem because it doesn't explain getting lower-case `ã` rather than upper-case `Ã`.

Comment: If I write ```encoding='utf-8``` I obtain the error ```UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 74: invalid continuation byte```

Comment: Ah right, `0xe9` is `é` in Latin-1, so looks like I was on the wrong track there. Sorry, I'm stumped :(

Comment: What happens if you don't do the `text.replace` and `re.sub` steps?

Comment: The documents do not change. I do not have the 'ã ' problem

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: 3.9. I find the same error with both notebook and pycharm

Comment: Please update your question with the file content read in binary mode. That is, please do: `print(open(fpath, 'rb').read())` and copy and paste the output to the question, so that we can see exactly what input data you're dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

Your file is probably written using the UTF-8 encoding (which is vastly used by default by text editors). For example, the word `élève` is encoded :

- `b'\xc3\xa9l\xc3\xa8ve'` using UTF-8
- `b'\xe9l\xe8ve'` using latin-1

When you read and UTF-8 encoded file using a latin-1 encoding, it will use the [latin-1 byte map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). The `\xa9` byte will be translated into `©` and `\xa8` into `¨`. Printing the latin-1 decoded byte encoded UTF-8 string `élève` gives `Ã©lÃ¨ve`. Now as stated in the [re documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), `\w` match any Unicode word character (or alphanumeric). Here, it simply removes `©` and `¨`, returning you the not wanted `Ã lÃ ve`.

You must use the correct encoding. When manipulating data (using read and write in code), you must know how it has been encoded and how to decode it. You should never let encoding unspecified. Here you may have to use UTF-8:

```py
import re

with open(fpath, encoding="utf-8") as f:
    text = f.read()
    print(text)
    text = text.replace(r"- ", "")
    # remove punctuation
    re.sub(r"[^\w\s]", " ", text)


with open(f"{fpath}.out", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(text)
```

Comment: I was thinking on these lines in the original comment (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76074563/trying-to-rewrite-text-files-in-latin-1-results-in-wrong-characters-for-letter#comment134166726_76074563). But I can't explain why OP sees lower-case `ã` rather than `Ã`. Also, trying to open the file as UTF-8 throws `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9` according to OP - so it does seem to have `\xe9` (expected if it's Latin-1 encoded) rather than `\xa9` (expected in UTF-8).

Comment: I was trying to figure out a way to work only with bytes but it seems impossible. I was trying to indicate that OP has to find the right encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be caused by the regular expression used to remove punctuation.

Instead of using r'[^\w\s]', you should use r'[^\w\s]' with the re.UNICODE flag to ensure it correctly handles non-ASCII characters. Can you try this?

```
text = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', ' ', text, flags=re.UNICODE)
```

Comment: Thank you, Grimlock for your suggestion, but the problem persists. I also tried without the ```replace``` part